# Why is one of the properties of vector spaces that it has a zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, axioms

Why do we state that "$A$ vector space has a zero vector", then we prove that for any vector space, the zero vector is unique?

Why don't we say instead (as a property) that a vector space has a unique zero vector?

Why is the property being general better?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What do you mean why don't we say from the beginning?

Comment: It is good mathematical strategy to posit the *least*-restrictive (most general) axioms.  Saying there *exists* a zero vector is less-restrictive than specifying a *specific* such vector.

Comment: @Youem The question is clear. OP is asking why don't include the uniqueness as part of the axiom.

Comment: Because if we include "uniqueness" in the requirements, then every single time we want to show something is a vector space (and we do that a lot!) we'd have to prove uniqueness. And it would be the same proof each time, so it would be a boring waste of people's time.

Comment: In general, when one defines axioms one wants the axioms to be as simple as possible. You could include uniqueness as part of the axiom. You could also include all the other basic properties of vector spaces as axioms too. That way you won't need to prove them. BUT if you do that, you will have more work every time you need to show that certain set with some operations is a vector space.

Comment: When you later need to prove something is a vector space, it is one less thing to have to prove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good mathematical strategy to posit the *least*-restrictive (most general) axioms.  Saying there exists a zero vector is less-restrictive than specifying a specific such vector.

Example:  Suppose you're defining the natural numbers.  You could posit $0$ is in the set and the operation of adding $1$ to any member to get another member.  That's all you need.

... OR you could (in principle) state that $0$ and $1$ are in the set and that you can add $2$ to any member to get another member.  Sure... that would work too, but is needlessly complex and doesn't reveal the underlying structure as well.